# Can't manually add item to listbox that is populated iterating through a list

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, datasource

In a C# WinForms project I'm querying a database to get a list of values to populate a listbox with. The query populates a List and then I iterate through that to add the list items to the listbox.

```
lsNewValuesList = dbGetNewValueInfo.GetNewValuesDgvData(strNewValuesQuery);

foreach (string strItem in lsNewValuesList)
{
    lsBxNewValues.Items.Add(strItem);
}
```

After that's done, I need to manually add an item to the top of the list, which I'm doing via, `lsBoxNewValues.Items.Insert(0, "DELETE");`. But when I run it I get the message,

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Here is a screenshot of the error (to clarify some questions):
[image]

Looking into that I'm understanding that error arises when the listbox is populated with a datasource, but I'm just populating it from a string list. Is that, technically, a datasource then?

How do I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

**[UPDATE]**

Okay, I've done some fiddling around, albeit without resolving my issue, and I've tried the following:

```
lsNewValuesList = dbGetNewValueInfo.GetNewValuesDgvData(strNewValuesQuery);

lsNewValuesList.Insert(0, "DELETE");
lsBxNewValues.DataSource = lsNewValuesList;
//foreach (string strItem in lsNewValuesList)
//{
//  lsBxNewValues.Items.Add(strItem);
//}
```

Instead of inserting "DELETE" in the ListBox (which is what I was originally trying and was causing the error), I inserted it at index 0 of the List, the datasource of the ListBox, and then set the ListBox's datasource. "DELETE" is showing up in the ListBox, but it's getting alphabetized along with the rest of the items. I'm not doing any sorting of the list or the ListBox - I'm using `ORDER BY` in the database query, however. CyberZeus suggested I use `Refresh()` on the ListBox, but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Are you perhaps setting the `DataSource` property somehere between the `foreach` loop and then call to `Insert`?

Comment: @mm8, Nope - `GetNewValuesDgvData()`, just runs a db query that populates `lsNewValuesList`.

Comment: Are you trying to add Items to `lsNewValuesList` or `lsBxNewValues`? What is `lsNewValuesList`? It doesn't look like it's a Control. Is that a typo? What object/collection is `GetNewValuesDgvData()` actually returning? Which object/collection generates the exception? Why aren't you setting the `lsBxNewValues.DataSource` instead of adding items one at a time? Or, are you?

Comment: @Jimi, I'm trying to add "DELETE" to the top of the ListBox. '`lsNewValuesList` is the `List<string>` that I am iterating through to populate the ListBox, `lsBoxNewValues`. Those are not typos (similar in name, I know, but not typos in either case). The object that `GetNewValuesDgvData()` returns is a `List<string>`. I get the error on the line, `lsBxNewValues.Items.Insert(0, "DELETE");`, which is called after the function that populates the ListBox.

Comment: You have a typo, then: in your comment, you've just written `lsBxNewValues.Items.Insert(0, "DELETE");`, in your question `lsNewValues.Items.Insert(0, "DELETE");`. You are setting (one of your) ListBox(es) DataSource (`lsBxNewValues.DataSource`) somewhere. Or you're referring to the wrong object. At this point, are you sure what control generates the exception?

Comment: @Jimi, you are correct, I did have a typo in my question (which I fixed). I am not using `lsBxNewValues.DataSource` anywhere in my code. I added a screenshot of the error to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a list of strings is a datasource.
You have to add the data retrieved from the database to the datasource of the ListBox. You may need to refresh the ListBox.

Comment: CyberZeus, are you saying to do something like `ListBox.DataSource = lsNewValuesList` and then add the additional item to the listbox (`lsBxNewValues.Items.Insert(0, "DELETE");`?